# Write List into .csv file

Tags: java, csv

I have a list and want to write the data into .csv file.

This is an example how my list looks like:

[image]

Each element contains the values from a database table.  I deleted the information here. For example List[0] contains id = 1, name = Test, date = 02.02.2016 etc.

This is my code so far, but I have no Idea how to continue.

```
  List<String> lines = Arrays.asList("ColumnHeader", "ColumnHeader", " ColumnHeader","ColumnHeader","ColumnHeader");
  Path file = Paths.get(test.csv");
  Files.write(file, lines, Charset.forName("Windows-1252"));
```

Comment: Is your list a `List<List<String>>`?

Comment: What is the structure of your list? You mentioned that list[0] contains few fields, but how? one string (comma separated) or there is an object?

Comment: as others have asked: the entries in `temp` (see screenshot) are reference datatypes?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/). This library contains tools for writing `List` and array objects to csv files, and even database result sets can be written directly to a file.

```java
CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter("yourfile.csv"), '#');
java.sql.ResultSet myResultSet = ....
writer.writeAll(myResultSet, includeHeaders);
writer.close();
```